# The set of all Symmetries of a regular polygon

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Definition: For each $n \geq 3$, Let $P_n$ be a regular polygon of n sides. A **symmetry** of $P_n$ is a bijection $P_n \to P_n$ that preserves distances and maps adjacent vertices onto adjacent vertices.

I need to prove that the set of all symmetries of $P_n$ is a group under the binary operation of composition of functions. Is the definition mean the mapping is a cycle $(12 \cdots n)$ or its inverse? I don't think I understood properly. If it is, the set can't be a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group of symmetries of a regular $n$-gon is often referred to as the **Dihedral Group $D_{2n}$.**

[Wikipedia Entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group)

Showing this is indeed a group consists of checking the group axioms:

1. Associativity of the operation, $$a(bc)=(ab)c$$
2. Existence of identity element $$\exists e\in G \ \text{such that }\forall a\in G:e\cdot a=a\cdot e = a$$
3. Inverses $$\forall a\in G\ \exists a^{-1}\in G\text{ such that }a\cdot a^{-1}=a^{-1}\cdot a =e$$

The definition does not mean the bijection $P_n\to P_n$ is a cycle, it just means that a bijection which preserves distances and maps adjacent vertices onto adjacent vertices is a symmetry.

So what *are* the symmetries of a polygon?

Well, let's take the equilateral triangle as an example. The actions you can take are:

1. You can do nothing (which is the same as rotating by $0^{\circ}$), since it does nothing, call this $\{e\}$
2. You can rotate clockwise by $120^{\circ}$, or you can rotate clockwise by $240^{\circ}$ Call these $\{r_1,r_2\}$
3. Finally, you can flip over each of the 3 axes of symmetry, call them $\{s_1,s_2,s_3\}$

So there are $6$ elements in this group.

Then, convince yourself (maybe by drawing it out) that combining any of these actions will give you another action. Try and notice patterns when considering the square, or the pentagon!